# Unity crashes with nvidia and any driver. Workaround?

Tags: unity, nvidia

Is it possible to disable Unity 3d in Ubuntu 12.10?

I had to use Unity 2d with Ubuntu 12.04 as Unity would constantly crash and restart. This problem persists in 12.10 with any driver I select in the panel, including the open source driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity ([Unity3d](http://unity3d.com/) is actually a game engine) is the only UI shell in 12.10, which means, you need to install an alternative before removing it (don't think there ever was a way to disable). 
Press `ctrl-alt-f1` to get a tty, login with your username and password, and install Gnome Classic with

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

To get back to the login screen, try running `sudo service lightdm restart`.

You should then be able to select Gnome Classic (no effects) as session from the login scren.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that works in my case. Deleting ~/.compiz/session before logging in stops Unity from crashing. This file gets recreated when logging out so you have to delete it before each login.